# Mysql Insert into Select Values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jtable

I have this query in my program with JTables:

```
prs = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reportTable (main_id,cat,pro,price,qty,total)"+
                                        " SELECT main_id,catId,proId,priceId"+
                                        " FROM mainTable"+
                                        " WHERE main_id= " + table.getValueAt(i,0));
```

The values of  "qty" and "total" will come from the Jtable.
How will I be able to put the qty and total as a query?

Comment: use binding variables

Comment: Can you use a JOIN with Jtable and mainTable so that you can get all the values for insert from the query

Comment: You could hard code in your select. See [fiddle](sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b15b23)

Comment: You want to insert in table 6 columns (main_id,cat,pro,price,qty,total). But give only 4 columns.

Comment: @plutov.by I have 6 columns in total. 4 came from the database and the other 2 came from the user input.

Answer (score 0):

use select statement as--> select main_id,catid,proid,priceid,qty,total from maintable join jtable on maintable.proid=jtable.proid(or any other mapping id between two tables) where main_id=table.getValueAt(i,0));

Comment: what about my reportTable?

Comment: INSERT INTO reportTable (main_id,cat,pro,price,qty,total) select main_id,catid,proid,priceid,qty,total from maintable join jtable on maintable.proid=jtable.proid(or any other mapping id between two tables) where main_id=table.getValueAt(i,0));